# Insert additional image into checkbox element JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile phone application using JQuery Mobile, and there's a visual effect I'd like to achieve with a list of checkbox elements.  Basically I'd like to insert a small icon (an image) into the body of each checkbox element in the following position:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this with JQuery Mobile?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that?
http://jsfiddle.net/KADqA/23/
just add some styling to the image, should work.

(the javascript is not really useful in that case. was a sample on how to add a Link into this field: http://jsfiddle.net/KADqA/)